# LuaTeX, \discretionary, and tcolorbox

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox, discretionary

The following MWE renders differently in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX: XeLaTeX has a line break, but LuaLaTeX doesn't.  pdfLaTeX produces the same result as XeLaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\hyphenpenalty=10000

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \rule{.8\linewidth}{1ex}\discretionary{}{}{}\rule{.8\linewidth}{1ex}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

- LuaLaTeX: [image: lualatex]
- XeLaTeX: [image: xelatex]

It seems that `tcolorbox` interacts with `\discretionary`, but only in LuaLaTeX.  Why is that?

Comment: LuaTeX uses a different hyphentation algorithm. Also I'd like to call into question the usefulness of “hyphenating” two consecutive black boxes.

Comment: There is an example on page 78 of the manual. And `\hyphenpenalty=10000` seems to be the key.

Comment: The non-LuaTeX behavior can be explained by the fact that the penalty when breaking at a discretionary whose pre-break text is empty is `\exhyphenpenalty`, which is 50 by default in plain TeX (and thus < 10000). Setting `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` therefore prevents the break when compiling with pdfTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: @HenriMenke this is a MWE, hence the boxes; if you replace them with a long word, you'll see the same result.

Comment: @frougon: This makes sense, but then why is the behavior specific to `tcolorbox`?  None of the engines add a break if I remove the `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @egreg The manual shows that LuaTeX support per-hyphen penalties, but it doesn't address the interaction with tcolorbox: if I remove `tcolorbox`, then all engines behave the same here.

Comment: if you remove the tcolorbox you have two rules of with 0.8\linewidth and there will no break because of the underfull line.

Comment: @Clément As Ulrike said, lines are shorter inside the `tcolorbox`, which helps. More precisely, before the `tcolorbox`, `\showthe\dimexpr \linewidth - \parindent\relax` prints `330.0pt` whereas `\showthe\linewidth` prints `313.70206pt` inside the `tcolorbox`. But using `\tracingparagraphs=1` shows that there is more to it: inside the `tcolorbox`, `\emergencystretch` is `30.00005pt` and this does help to get the badness of the first line < `\tolerance` when breaking at the discretionary (note that `\tolerance`  is  `9999` in the `tcolorbox` while it is `200` outside...).

Comment: Note that without `tcolorbox`, you can easily have a break at the discretionary with pdfTeX if you use `\raggedright`, since there is no underfull `\hbox` in this case.